# Google Map View only shows grey tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, intellij-idea, google-maps-android-api-2

i followed all the online solutions however nothing changes i still keep getting the grey tiles on the map and the map doesnt work...

The tutorials specify that i need an api-key using the MD5 fingerprint, however google codes doesnt accept it and instead it requires SHA-1 fingerprint...

Here's my code:

Main.java:

```
package com.thenewboston.googleMaps;


import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;


public class Main extends MapActivity{

MapView map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mvMain);
    map.setTraffic(true);

    if(map.isShown()){
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }

    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setSatellite(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyAms_xsUt-l-qlIR6fuAd0jfaYRsBIV3bg"
        android:id="@+id/mvMain"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.thenewboston.googleMaps"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
            android:name="Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

**NOTE**: im using linux and Intellij Idea and im developing on API 8 (old tutorials)

PLZ HELP

Answer (score 0):

I can see a bunch of stuff mising (like api key on manifest)

Check http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html. It may help.
Imo this one is better http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc

Comment: the Api_key is in the xml layout as it was instructed by the tutorial

Comment: @Tharwat please check the tutorial i linked above, its a V2 implementation and its a step by step tutorial. Please be careful when choosing the right API on the google console.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the actual key you have produces which is for Google Maps API V2 and the code you are using which is a Google Maps API V1 objects like the `MapActivity` and `MapView` objects.

And this is the reason you are not seeing any map, Google does not provide API keys for Google Maps API V1 as it deprecated for some time now. So you will have to change you code to Google Maps API V2 objects.

To get you started you can take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps API V2 in your application:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: The thing is i read here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key
that V2 and this code is only supported for API 12 or later... im using API 8 .. Will this be a problem?